# Error saving variables into a database

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I'm trying to save a article and title into my database. I'm using OOP programming language (getters, setters) with mysqli. Here you can see my code from the class.

```
<?php
class Article {
    private $m_sTitle;
    private $m_sArticle;

public function __set($p_sProperty, $p_vValue) 
{
        switch($p_sProperty) 
        {
            case "Title" :
                $this -> m_sTitle = $p_vValue;
                break;
            case "Article" :
                $this -> m_sArticle = $p_vValue;
                break;
        }
}   

public function __get($p_sProperty) 
{
        $vResult = null;
        switch($p_sProperty) 
        {
            case "Title" :
                $vResult = $this -> m_sTitle;
                break;
            case "Article" :
                $vResult = $this -> m_sArticle;
                break;
        }
}

public function saveArticle() 
    {
        include("connection.php");
            $sSql = "INSERT INTO tblArticles
                (titel, 
                article, 
                ) 
                VALUES 
                ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $this -> m_sTitle) . "', 
                '" .mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $this -> m_sArticle) . "', 
                );";


        if (!$mysqli -> query($sSql))
        {
            throw new Exception("Something went wrong");
        }

    }
}

?>
```

Here you can see the code in the php file.

```
if(isset($_GET['title'])=="")
{
 //do nothing   
}
else {
    $titel = $_GET['title'];
 $artikel = $_GET['content'];


include("assets/connection.php");
include("assets/article.class.php");

$article1 = new Article;
$article1 -> Title = $titel;
$article1 -> Article = $artikel;
$article1 -> saveArticle() ;
}
```

I receive this error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Something went wrong' in ../assets/article.class.php:48 Stack trace: #0 ../index.php(52): Article->saveArticle() #1 {main} thrown in ..assets/article.class.php on line 48 (this line $article1 = new Article;)

Thanks for the response!

**Problem solved with replacing a query(type errors), you can see the working part (query) below this sentence.**

```
 $sSql = "INSERT INTO tblArticles
                (titel, 
                article 
                ) 
                VALUES 
                ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $this -> m_sTitle) . "', 
                '" .mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $this -> m_sArticle) . "');";
```

Comment: Can you post the structure of tblArticles table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an unwanted comma after `article` in your query:

```
INSERT INTO tblArticles
            (titel, 
            article,) VALUES ...
```

Comment: you're my man! There was a , to much where you said, and also in the end of my query! works fine now. Thank you very much for the answer!